# How to return dynamic type with @method PHPDoc tag in PHPStorm for static methods

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-7, phpdoc, magic-methods

I have tried to solve this for some time now, because it would help a lot in developing if stuff like this would be autocompleted and recognised.

So, I'm using Laravel and Eloquent uses a lot of magic methods to use all the Query magic directly on Models as well.

What I did so far, was preparing a base class `BaseModel` extending it from Eloquent-model and add the `@method` PHPDoc tags to specify that my inheriting models are having these functions as well.

Now there is this keyword which is supposedly used for fluent methods `$this` to indicate that the same instance is returned. The whole thing works when I use it that way e.g.

```
/**
 * @method $this find(int $id)
 */
class BaseModel extends Model
```

But what if I want to call them statically? Like this

```
User::find(1)->email;
```

I can change the line to this

```
 @method static BaseModel find(int $id)
```

Now it works as long as I chain some query methods, but it doesn't find the email it gives a

```
Field not found in BaseModel
```

This also applies to `$this` and `self` and I haven't encountered another method.

Is there actually a way to solve this? I could paste the same tag to every model and return the respective class, but that would be a little overkill just for convenience.

Thank you for you help in advance

Comment: checkout this package: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
It does those things for you :)

Comment: I added that and built the helper files, it is still not working

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend Model class to recognize Eloquent methods just add above class PHPDoc comment

```
@mixin Eloquent
```

Example

```
<?php namespace App;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @mixin Eloquent
 */
class User extends Model {
```

Comment: That would be my preferred solution if it worked with static calls as well, but unfortunately `$user->withTrashed()` works, but `User::withTrashed()` does not, it warns that you cannot call the method `withTrashed()` statically, even though it's possible

Comment: It could not be possible to use `withTrashed()` statically. It is fetching through query.

You need at least `User::get()->withTrashed()` but `withTrashed()` will not be recognized it is extension of `Eloquent`, so you will need to extend `Eloquent` to recognize these new stuff.

Comment: What I did at the moment was creating `trait ModelTrait` and `using` it inside my `BaseModel` and then in the `PHPDoc Block` I put the following `@method static self withTrashed()` but I have to do this with every Eloquent or Query-Builder function